# maven-compiler plugin skipping test case while packaging

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have a maven plugin configuration something like this. But it always skip test case execution on the heroku server side how can i enable test case to run. I have tried `<skip>false</skip>` but it is not working as it intended . In my Local machine when i do a mvn install or mvn package it is running the test cases very smoothly .

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <!-- compile for Java 1.8 -->
            <configuration>                            
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>               
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Test are not part of the Maven Compiler Plugin, rather concerned by the Maven Surefire Plugin, could you provide its configuration, if any? Do you have any parent configured in your pom?

Answer (score -2):

For running build without tests we can use maven command line options for skipping tests- mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install

Comment: Sudeep is asking the question the other way around, he / she wants to run the tests